# MySql Error through php to mysql

Tags: php, mysql

```
$query= "insert into question_table(std_id,question,date,status)
         values('8','This is Rahul's First Question?',now(),'N')";
```

I want to pass this query through **php** to **mysql** but it create error for `This is Rahul's First Question?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to escape the question variable (in fact should escape where needed):

```
$question = mysqli_real_escape_string($question);
```

Then use prepared statements.

But in your case it would be something like:

```
$query= "insert into question_table(std_id,question,date,status)
         values('8','".$question."',now(),'N')";
```

Answer (score 0):

In PHP you'd want to, at the very least, use something like [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) to execute this:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare(
  'INSERT INTO question_table (std_id, question, date, status)'.
  ' VALUES (:std_id, :question, NOW(), :status)'
);

$stmt->execute(array(
  'std_id' => 8,
  'question' => "This is Rahul's First Question?",
  'status' => 'N'
));
```

The important thing here is using *placeholder values* and supplying the data external to the query. If you don't use something like that you **must** manually escape using a database escaping function. Most PHP MySQL drivers expose something of this sort, like the [PDO `quote` function](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php).